# with AngularJS, using {{ and }} as literals

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a page with AngularJS, which uses {{ and }} to mark a section as an expression.

However, I need to make the literal strings "{{" and "}}" appear on the page as visible to the user.

I have tried using the HTML special character alternatives, but they get evaluated by AngularJS as {{ and }} anyway. The regular javascript escape key '\' does not work either.

Can anyone tell me how to make AngularJS ignore these symbols?

Comment: Tada ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, use the [`ng-non-bindable`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) directive, eg

```
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make this:

```
{{ '{{' + 'any text or variable' + '}}' }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think this would work. It seems like the ngNonBindable solution might be the better way to go though.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that way, It's definitely the best way to do it